# Postmessage function is not working in mobile but working in desktop

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I am trying to create the widget the will have one button, when someone click on the button a popup comes. That popups contain the button too, that will do task.

Here is the popup code-

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-btn" id="closeModalBtn">&times;</span>
            <iframe id="modelIframe" src="base_url/modelviewer.html" style="width: 280px; height: 200px;" allow="xr-spatial-tracking" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <p>View this product in 3D</p>
            <button id="activateAR" style="padding: 10px 10px;border: none; ">See in 3D</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when this poup up is visible and user click on the button (with id "activateAR"), I call the following function-

```
function activateARFunction() {
    console.log("data",document);
    const iframe = document.getElementById('modelIframe');
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('activateAR', '*');     
}


document.getElementById('activateAR').addEventListener('click', activateARFunction);
```

and `modelviewer.html` (where I am receiving the message)-

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log("button without data ","received");
    if (event.data === 'activateAR') {
        console.log("button ","received");
         
    }
});
</script>
```

When I run this code in the desktop, my `modelviewer.html` receive the `postmessage` data i.e.

```
console.log("button without data ","received");
```

However, when I run it in mobile, it does not print anything. No error in console too.

Comment: Which browser and OS? Are both documents same-origin? Is the iframe in view when the click happens? Are you sure you listener has been added correctly (can you add a simple log outside of the handler to ensure the script ran)? What if you log the `contentWindow`, is it the expected one?

Comment: Chrome Mobile - V118.0.5993.80 

Nops both are cross origin ( I am placing this code as the widget on the other website). 

Yes, Iframe and button both are on same popup. 

Yes, listener are correct as they are working in case of desktop. I console the  iframe and it was expected one.

Comment: By "in view" I really meant in the viewport, i.e. that you can see its content when you click the button. IIRC there were some experiments made to basically unload the iframes that are out of viewport for battery saving purposes, it would be possible that such an experiment causes a bug preventing the message event to reach the iframe. Anyways, did you try to [reach out](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/wizard) to Chrome's team? That's a bug, they ought to know about it. (Also the OS part is quite important, since iOS browsers are all Safari actually)

Comment: @Kaiido I tried putting "alert("hello")" inside the window. addEventListener and its worked. 

So it mean my postmessage is working and issue is something else. But still console.log is not printing.

Answer (score -1):

Nah, don’t fight with mobile browsers, you will age too quickly!

Simply implement a simple message receiver function in the parent and send back from the iframe whatever you want to console.log

Answer (score -2):

> However, when I run it in mobile, it does not print anything. No error in console too.

I can't reproduce your issue. Is it possible that you are expecting to see console output on the mobile device browser without [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)? If so, that could be the cause of the confusion.

Below is a self-contained example that you can use to reproduce success. The example updates text content in the DOM directly so that feedback can be seen in the browser viewport without the need for viewing a JavaScript console stream in a debugger:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>so-77349441</title>
  <style>#modelIframe { display: block; height: 2rem; width: 20rem; }</style>
  <script type="module">
    function activateARFunction() {
      const iframe = document.getElementById("modelIframe");
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("activateAR", { targetOrigin: "*" });
    }
  
    document.getElementById("activateAR").addEventListener(
      "click",
      activateARFunction,
    );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <!--
      The value of the "src" attribute in the iframe element below
      is a base64 encoded representation of the following HTML (because Stack
      Overflow does not allow for multiple resources in code snippets):

      <!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script type="module">
          window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
            document.body.textContent = "Message received";
            if (event.data === "activateAR") {
              document.body.textContent = "Expected message received";
            }
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>Awaiting message...</body>
      </html>
    -->
    <iframe
      id="modelIframe"
      src="data:text/html;base64,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"
    ></iframe>
    <button id="activateAR">Click</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```